# Spring Boot Returning 405 instead of 404 for POST to unknown URL

Tags: java, spring-boot

Disclaimer: I'm new to Java, Spring, and Spring Boot.

I'd like to have Spring Boot return a 404 when trying to POST to a URL that doesn't exist. However, right now it's returning a 405, with an Allow header that only includes GET and HEAD. Is there a way to customize which HTTP methods are allowed so that I get a 404? I've tried implementing a custom ErrorController, but that doesn't seem to work.

**To be clear**: this is when I'm POSTing to a URL that shouldn't be matched by *any* of my defined endpoints, e.g http://example.com/some-bogus-thing

If any more information is needed to diagnose this, I'd be happy to provide it. Given my unfamiliarity with the platform, I'm not sure what's relevant.

Comment: You need to annotate your method with @RequestMapping and set the method attribute to the desired type.

Comment: Create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post the code. I can reproduce this exact behaviour, but I can't explain it, that's why a comment and no answer.

Comment: I am seeing this as well and the the questioner is correct. Looking at the source it seems that a 404 is only returned for a GET request to an invalid URL. For all other requests, for whatever reason, the framework by default returns a 405.

Answer (score 4):

`HTTP 405 (Method not found)` is returned, `when URL exists` and you try to use an HTTP Method that is not allowed on that particular URL mapping.

if you invoke a POST on below `.../test` then it will return HTTP 405 and vice versa.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

if there is no URL mapping for any of the HTTP methods, then it will return HTTP 404.

To know all the current mappings on that particular boot instance, just to go browser

```
http://localhost:8080/mappings
```

Comment: Yes, the situation you describe is one where I'd want to return a 405. However, my scenario is when I'm posting to a URL that *doesn't* exist. I want that to be a 404, but Spring Boot is returning a 405.

Comment: That's not possible. If there is no URL mapping, it will return 404. If it returns 405 means, there is a mapping. Cross check it with the mapping from `localhost:8080/mappings`.

Comment: When I go to localhost:8080/mappings, I get a page with a pink error message up at the top that says: `This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 25: expected '>'
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.` What template is this trying to render? I can correct it, but I have no idea where to look.

Comment: k139 is correct. If no URL mapping is available, it will return a 404. If you try to use a wrong HTTP method to invoke a controller method, you will get a 405. Also you need to share relevant code, so that people can help you without which it is shooting in dark.

Comment: Post *what* relevant code, though? I'm not just going to spam my entire app up onto SO.

Comment: I am seeing this as well and the the questioner is correct. Looking at the source it seems that a 404 is only returned for a GET request to an invalid URL. For all other requests, for whatever reason, the framework by default returns a 405.

Answer (score 1):

Check here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4876

The solution is to have a setup like this:
spring:
  mvc:
    static-path-pattern: /static/**

Comment: This was a good clue for me.  There could be some generic handlers confusing the issue.  In my case it was related to a custom `ErrorController`.  The 405 response includes `Allow: GET`, but doing a `GET` returns a 404.  The [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4876) suggests that this has been fixed, but it looks to be like it has not.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still encounter this issue:
This is a bug on spring framework 4.2.4, please refer to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18516
And as it said, this issue has been fixed since 4.3 RC1.